# Evaluating the double integral of $\sin(y)\cdot e^{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The task I'm given is to find the numbers $A$ and $B$ so that if

$$I = \iint_D\sin(y)\cdot e^{x^2+y^2} dxdy$$

then $A\leq I\leq B$, where the integration area $D$ is the top half of the circle $\{ x^2+y^2\leq 1, y\geq 0 \}$.

Comment: $0\leq \sin(y)e^{x^2+y^2}\leq e^{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Also, use $y-y^3/6\lt\sin y\lt y$

Comment: can we use polar coordinates and say $r^2\le 1$ and that $\theta\le\pi$?

Comment: @Henry Lee, yes, that would probably do the trick.